# ASP.NET Login control without a Username

Tags: c#, asp.net, login-control

Is it possible to use the standard ASP.NET login control, but just ask the user for a password? I am using a template, but the runtime complains that;

```
Login1: LayoutTemplate does not contain an IEditableTextControl with ID UserName for the username.
```

My current thinking, is to add the control with `style="display:none;"` which seems lame. The existing project already uses FormsAuthentication, so plan B might be to roll my own Authentication method.

**Update**
I have a 2 step login process. Step 1: "Who are you?" and Step 2: "What is your password?"

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I'd sure style it with display:none long before rolling my own.

Comment: +1 Currently the best solution so far. Also can't use a hidden control either :(

Answer (score 3):

What functionality do you want from the Login Control? I assume your rolling your own authentication mechanism? Are you really going to gain a lot by reusing the login control? If so set the style to display:none.

**Edit**

If you identify the user on a previous page why not show a disabled textbox with the username or part of the username in it? I've seen some banks do this where on the first page you put the login and maybee the state you live in, then it validates that, then shows you the first three characters of the login name, and your site key and asks for your password.

Comment: Yes, you're very close to what Im trying to do, except the UserId in this case is some crazy random string. I'll stick with the display:none, and if someone disables styles they'll see why I hid the field :)

Comment: Makes sense in your case, you should also make the textbox readonly so if they disable styles they can't easily muck with it.

Comment: +1 Readonly - good idea. I know that their user Guid is and am not reading from the field but it'll keep some messers at bay.

Answer (score 2):

**Updated Answer**:

Your best bet is to transform the login control into a label, and then display that over the empty textbox for their password.

**Ye Olde Answer**:

Why do you want to do that; what happens if two users have the same password?

Comment: @GeorgeStocker did you or someone happened to blog on this ?

Comment: @HarshBaid Na, I didn't - although the changes in website security over the past few years have rendered it somewhat obsolete.

Comment: Where did the comments go now ?

Comment: @HarshBaid Looking at them, I realized they were years old and the discussion wasn't really relevant now.

Answer (score 1):

I haven't tested this, and it may sound a little silly, but you might be able to write a wrapper for the login control, like a UserControl with a LoginForm as a property - Then use the Init event to assign values from the controls you create to update the values onto the LoginForm (property)

If the property doesn't work, you might be able to put it on the page, but make it hidden.